# Increase compiler stack size of MSVC

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, compiler-errors, stack-overflow, msvc14

I am testing a code that is using a large number of variables and some `__forceinline` functions. As a result, I am getting the following compilation error:

```
Fatal error C1063: compiler limit: compiler stack overflow
```

This makes perfect sense as the compiler stack gets filled up for keeping track of the information of the variables.

[MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-6.0/aa229021(v=vs.60)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) suggests: `Simplify the program by splitting it into smaller source files, and recompile`, which I agree is the solution to my problem. However, I want to test my program as it is by increasing the compiler stack size if possible.

Note that I am not trying to increase the program stack size which could be done using `/STACK` linker option.

I am using Visual Studio 2019 (v.16.3.9, MSVC++ 14.23).

Thanks.